# data-toggle not working with following latest bootstrap links

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I was trying to use data-toggle but the code given below is not working. Please help me out of it.
I have used latest bootstrap cdn links.
Code is given below.

```
    <html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Click</button>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need jquery before bootstrap.min.js

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cdeedej3/)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else comes across this problem in 2022 and you have your CDN/File in correct spot -- Try this:

```
//---On the button

//Replace
data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"

//With
data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse"

// Current CDNs
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

See Bootstrap documentation for more detail
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/

Comment: B5 doesn't need a **JQuery** import.